# TestCafe: how to set a button component on a page to a pressed state where its a click but not released?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm creating an automated test to test the different specs or attributes of an element (button component) but in order to do this, I have to force the button to specific states like - pressed and disabled states. I have already done it for the focus and hover states.

1. how to set a button element/component on a page to a pressed state where the button is clicked but not released - similar to a key down? Asking since the specs (Text color and background color) of a clicked state and a pressed state are different.
2. how to set a button element/component on a page to a disabled state.
3. Is it even possible to force element state similar to inspect/dev tools using the browser?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Currently you cannot provide the `mousedown` action without a further `mouseup` action as well as forcing an element state like in DevTools.

However, if you want to set button state to `disabled`, I think the [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) mechanism can help you. See the following code:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture ``
    .page ``;

const btn = Selector('button');

const setDisabled = ClientFunction(() => {
    btn().setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}, { dependencies: { btn } });

test('test', async t => {
    await setDisabled();
});
```

Comment: thank you! I was able to set it to disabled. is it possible to mousedown then get the specs like background color before a mouseup? or maybe set the state to active state?

Comment: It is not possible to use individual mouse actions phases (e.g., mousedown, mouseup). You can track updates on this enhancement here: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3750